# Dart - An expression whose value can be null must be null-checked before it can be dereferenced

Tags: flutter, dart

This was my Dart code after initializing *fun* by adding *?*

However, it is still not working and throws an error that says "An expression whose value can be null must be null-checked before it can be dereferenced"

```
int add(int a, int b) => a + b;

Function? fun;

void main() {
  fun = add;
  
  var result = fun(20, 30);
  
  print("Result is ${result}");
}
```

How do I null-check *fun*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You compare against a null, the analyzer deduces that after the successfull check the variable is not null:

```
void testFunction(Function? f) {
  if (f != null) {
     var result = f(20, 30);
     print("Result is ${result}");
  }
}
```

One caveat is it does not currently work with global variables:

> The analyzer can’t model the flow of your whole application, so it can’t predict the values of global variables or class fields.

See https://dart.dev/null-safety#using-variables-and-expressions

Also note that there isn’t a null-aware function call operator, but you can write:

```
function?.call(arg1, arg2);
```